# how not to load hasMany entities from database using Grails

Tags: grails, has-many

I've got 3 classes:

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    static belongsTo = [company: Company]
    String name
}

class Book {
     static mapping = {
        collection "documents"
        id generator: 'assigned',index: true, indexAttributes:[background:true, unique:true, dropDups:true] 
    }
    String id
    String name
}

class Company {
     static mapping = {
        collection "documents"
        id generator: 'assigned',index: true, indexAttributes:[background:true, unique:true, dropDups:true] 
    }
    String id
    String name
}
```

I want to use

```
Author author = Author.getByCompanyAndBook(1,1);
```

but when running this Grails retrieves all the Book objects from the database.

I need those Books only as identifiers for the Author and I am not going to use those objects.

Is there a way for me to force Grails not to fetch the Books and Companies from the database?

I tried to use:

```
static mapping = {
    books lazy: true
}
```

but still all of the Books and the Company were loaded.

Edit:

I am using mongo db as my database.

Comment: what grails version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird - collections are lazy by default, so getting an author shouldn't retrieve anything in the books collection until you access the books property. But regardless, even if it worked as expected I recommend that you avoid mapped collections. See [this talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) which shows why collections are unnecessarily expensive and provides workarounds to minimize the costs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I'm using Intellij Debugger to figure out what gets in return. i'm using mongodb so there is no way (at least that i know about) for me to check what was the exact query. but in the debugger i can access all of the Books data from the books collection.